# Batch File that moves all files and folders into a specific sub folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Trying to whip up a batch script that moves some files and folders around, and finding I can't quite get things right. I have a folder structure like so:

```
Thomas Jefferson 80564
     CPD
     Some Folder 1
     Some Folder 2
     File.txt
     File.pdf
George Washington 80746
     CPD
     Some Folder 1
```

Where there's a large number of folders which have some random files/folders within them. I've created a 'CPD' folder within these, and need to move ALL other existing content into the CPD folder. I've been messing around with something like this, but it's not quite working as I would like. Any simple way of getting this to process the intended way?

```
@echo off

rem Define the name of the specific subfolder
set "destination=CPD"
set "homepath=C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\APEGS Test"

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /ad /b "%homepath%\*"') DO (

for /d %%F in (*) do (
    move "%%F" "%destination%"
)

)

echo All files and folders moved to %destination%.
pause
```

Comment: So you need to move everything from `Thomas Jefferson 80564` folder to `CPD` folder within it, and everything from `George Washington 80746` folder to `CPD` folder within it and so on?

Comment: Yep that's exactly it. Ideally, post execution, within each 'parent folder', only the CPD folder remains, with all files/folders within it.

Comment: Unless there is a very good, and specific reason, please do not define a variable named using an already existing environment variable name. The default for `%HomePath%` is often ```\Users\%UserName%```.

Comment: Yep, I know. This was just me being lazy in testing, I wouldn't do this in prod. Sometimes the brain just uses the first variable that comes to mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my comment was right, maybe something like this will work for you. Let me know if I'm on the right track:

```
@echo off
set "root_folder=C:\Users\..."

for /d %%A in ("%root_folder%\*") do (
    if not exist "%%A\CPD\" md "%%A\CPD"
    for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a:-d "%%A" ^| findstr /v /i /c:"CPD"') do (
        move "%%A\%%F" "%%A\CPD\"
    )
    for /d %%D in ("%%A\*") do (
        if not "%%~nxD"=="CPD" move "%%A\%%~nxD" "%%A\CPD\"
    )
)

echo Completed.
```

Root folder is folder that contains `Thomas Jefferson` and other folders. Following your folder hierarchy example, you will get this:

```
Thomas Jefferson 80564
  CPD
    Some Folder 1
    Some Folder 2
    File.txt
    File.pdf
George Washington 80746
  CPD
    Some Folder 1
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you so much! I think I can see where I went off base to, so that's awesome.

Comment: Sure, not a problem. Consider up voting and accepting answer so future readers know it works. Ohh, didn't see you already did it.

Comment: Just a couple of constructive criticisms : ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs if these are used as metavariables. If a **file** named `cpd` exists, then the directory cannot be created and moving anything to `cpd` assuming it's a directory will fail. Since (let us assume) `cpd` is a directory, then the `/a-d` will exclude it from the `dir` listing, hence the `findstr` is not required; further, the `findstr` would exclude any filenames *containing* cpd - cure this by adding the `/x` option. The final `if` should be case-insensitive, just in case..

Comment: If you are able to edit my post right now, be my guest. I won't be able to do it in next few hours, so you can do it now so I don't forget to do it. Thanks for corrections.